# python StanfordDependencyParser output exit code 0

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

i want to parse my sentence . so i want use StanfordDependencyParser ,
everything is ok , there is no error but the output is not what i want.
i see no word of my sentence in result of output.
it seems stanfordparse doesnt work on my sentences .

i use this tools specifications :

1. python 3.6
2. nltk 3.1
3. jre1.8.0_162

i use below code for using stanford parse :

```
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
path_to_jar = 'D:/uni/Soft ware/2014-8-27/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser.jar'
path_to_models_jar = 'D:/uni/Soft ware/2014-8-27/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser-3.4.1-models.jar'
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)
result = dependency_parser.raw_parse('I shot an elephant in my sleep')
dep = next(result)
print(dep)
```

at the output,i cant see any part of my sentence **'I shot an elephant in my sleep'** at the result , it seems that something is wrong.
the output is :

```
E:\python_pycharm_project\gensim_cbow\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/python_pycharm_project/gensim/venv/Cbow_gensim_2
defaultdict(<function DependencyGraph.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000003E2EA0>,
{0: {'address': 0,
             'ctag': 'TOP',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'root': [2]}),
             'feats': None,
             'head': None,
             'lemma': None,
             'rel': None,
             'tag': 'TOP',
             'word': None},
         1: {'address': 1,
             'ctag': 'PRP',
 'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 2,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'nsubj',
             'tag': 'PRP',
             'word': 'I'},
         2: {'address': 2,
             'ctag': 'VBD',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                                 {'dobj': [4],
                                  'nsubj': [1],
                                  'prep': [5]}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 0,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'root',
             'tag': 'VBD',
             'word': 'shot'},
         3: {'address': 3,
             'ctag': 'DT',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 4,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'det',
             'tag': 'DT',
             'word': 'an'},
         4: {'address': 4,
             'ctag': 'NN',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'det': [3]}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 2,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'dobj',
             'tag': 'NN',
             'word': 'elephant'},
         5: {'address': 5,
             'ctag': 'IN',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'pobj': [7]}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 2,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'prep',
             'tag': 'IN',
             'word': 'in'},
         6: {'address': 6,
             'ctag': 'PRP$',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 7,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'poss',
             'tag': 'PRP$',
             'word': 'my'},
         7: {'address': 7,
             'ctag': 'NN',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'poss': [6]}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 5,
             'lemma': '_',
             'rel': 'pobj',
             'tag': 'NN',
             'word': 'sleep'}})
Process finished with exit code 0
```